Loop iteration is failing at second iteration
Objective: I intend to create a program that appends digits from user input, convert from ASCII to number and into an array (intArray), and also get their sum all using a loop that iterates 5 times. I am very new to assembly language programming so I'm having a really difficult time debugging the program.
So far this is the code I've been able to come up with. It compiles and links successfully. After execution upon the second iteration, it fails with an error:

Enter an integer: 49 
Enter an integer: 50 
zsh: segmentation fault out/solution

Please what am I doing wrong?
section .bss
    input RESB 10 ; reserve 10 bytes for input

section .data
    list db 1,2,3,4,5
    prompt db "Enter an integer: ", 0
    prompt_len equ $ - prompt ; length of the prompt

    result_msg db "The sum is: ", 0
    result_msg_len equ $ - result_msg

    buffer db 12 dup(0)     ; buffer for input
    intArray dd 5 dup(0)
    arraySize db 0
    sum dd 0

section .text

global _start
_start:
    mov ecx, 5 ; loop 5 times

loop_prompt_handler:
    ; print the prompt to enter input
    mov eax, 4              ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1              ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
    mov ecx, prompt         ; message to print
    mov edx, prompt_len     ; number of bytes to read
    int 0x80

    ; read the input
    mov eax, 3              ; sys_read
    mov ebx, 0              ; file descriptor 0 (stdin)
    mov ecx, input          ; message to read
    mov edx, 10             ; number of bytes to read
    int 0x80

    ; convert ASCII input to integer
    call str_to_int

    ; append to array
    mov ebx, [arraySize]    ; load current size of the array
    mov edx, intArray       ; load address of the array
    add edx, ebx            ; point to the end of the array
    mov [edx], eax          ; store the input number at the end of the array

    ; increment array size
    inc byte [arraySize]    ; increment array size

    ; add the input number to the sum
    add dword [sum], eax

    loop loop_prompt_handler ; loop_prompt_handler label if ecx is not zero

    ; print the result
    mov eax, 4              ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1              ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
    mov ecx, result_msg     ; message to print
    mov edx, result_msg_len ; number of bytes to read
    int 0x80

    ; convert sum to string
    mov eax, [sum]
    mov ecx, buffer         ; buffer containing the sum as a string
    call int_to_string

    ; print the sum
    mov eax, 4              ; sys_write
    mov ebx, 1              ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
    mov edx, 12             ; length of the buffer
    int 0x80

    ; exit
    mov eax, 1              ; sys_exit
    xor ebx, ebx            ; exit code
    int 0x80

str_to_int:
    ; ecx: pointer to input string
    ; eax: result
    xor eax, eax            ; clear eax
    xor edx, edx            ; clear edx

    str_to_int_loop:
        movzx edx, byte [ecx]
        test dl, dl
        jz str_to_int_end
        sub dl, '0'
        imul eax, eax, 10
        add eax, edx
        inc ecx
        jmp str_to_int_loop
    
    str_to_int_end:
        ret

int_to_string:
    ; eax contains the string to convert
    ; ecx points to the buffer to store the string
    mov edi, ecx
    add edi, 11
    mov byte [edi], 0
    dec edi

    .convert_loop:
        xor edx, edx
        mov ebx, 10
        div ebx
        add dl, '0'
        mov [edi], dl
        dec edi
        test eax, eax
        jnz .convert_loop

    inc edi
    mov ecx, edi
    ret


Now would be a great time to get a debugger up and running. If you single step your code, inspecting the values of registers and memory as you go, you can probably find the bug for yourself, or at least ask a more specific question.

You seem to be trying to use ecx as a loop counter, but you overwrite it each time you make a system call.

@NateEldredge Okay, I wish to make use of the edi register to handle message to read, as against the ecx. Is that proper?

No, you can't change the registers used for the system call arguments. The kernel is expecting them in those specific registers. Best would be to use edi or some other register for your loop counter.

You won't be able to use the loop instruction, but that's just as well, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently

Okay @NateEldredge. Thank you let me check it out

Okay for the implementation of the loop I decided to keep ecx for the string buffering, so now use esi to track the loop iteration, Dec esi at the start of the loop and cmp esi, 0. jz if to a new _end function and jmp to the start of the loop function. This was my work around overwriting ecx

Corrupted loop counter
The code is using the ECX register for two different purposes at the same time: the address for the buffer and the loop counter. Since you can't choose where to put the address, better pick a register like ESI for controlling the loop. In doing so, you will also have avoided the use of the slow loop instruction:
  mov  esi, 5 ; loop 5 times
loop_prompt_handler:
  ...
  dec  esi
  jnz  loop_prompt_handler

Superfluous characters

prompt db "Enter an integer: ", 0
prompt_len equ $ - prompt ; length of the prompt
result_msg db "The sum is: ", 0
result_msg_len equ $ - result_msg


There's no need to zero-terminate these messages. Currently, the print service will be outputting these as a superfluous space character. Just remove the zero or keep it and deduct 1 from the length:
prompt db "Enter an integer: "
prompt_len equ $ - prompt
result_msg db "The sum is: "
result_msg_len equ $ - result_msg

or:
prompt db "Enter an integer: ", 0
prompt_len equ $ - prompt - 1
result_msg db "The sum is: ", 0
result_msg_len equ $ - result_msg - 1

Numerous misleading comments
As an example, just these:

mov edx, prompt_len     ; number of bytes to read
...
mov ecx, input          ; message to read


These should really read: "number of bytes to write" and "buffer to read".
sys_read reports about the number of characters

; convert ASCII input to integer
call str_to_int


If you want your str_to_int to keep working from a zero-terminated string, then you'll have to zero-terminate the string yourself:
mov  eax, 3    ; sys_read
int  0x80      ; -> EAX
; Assuming no errors here, convert ASCII input to integer
mov  byte [input + eax], 0
call str_to_int


Reading from the terminal (stdin) the count in EAX includes the linefeed (10) that ends input.

Therefore, in your str_to_int, have the sub dl, '0' instruction followed by jb str_to_int_end so as to not erroneously treat the newline as a decimal digit.
Wrong-size operations

mov ebx, [arraySize]    ; load current size of the array
mov edx, intArray       ; load address of the array
add edx, ebx            ; point to the end of the array
mov [edx], eax          ; store the input number at the end of the array
inc byte [arraySize]    ; increment array size


The arraySize variable is defined as a byte, therefore it is wrong to read is as a dword. Just as bad, you store a dword but only increment the variable by 1 instead of by 4.
Two solutions:
movzx ebx, byte [arraySize]   ; {0,4,8,12,16}
mov   [intArray + ebx], eax
add   byte [arraySize], 4

or:
movzx ebx, byte [arraySize]   ; {0,1,2,3,4}
mov   [intArray + ebx * 4], eax
inc   byte [arraySize]

sys_write works length-based
There's no need to have int_to_string zero-terminate the string. The print service will output the number of bytes specified in EDX, so you should calculate that number instead of just passing the length of the whole buffer.
; print the sum
mov  eax, [sum]
mov  ecx, buffer
call int_to_string      ; -> ECX
mov  edx, buffer + 12
sub  edx, ecx
mov  ebx, 1             ; file descriptor 1 (stdout)
mov  eax, 4             ; sys_write
int  0x80


movzx ebx, [arraySize] is invalid, you have to specify the size as in movzx ebx, byte [arraySize]

@ecm Good catch! For a brief moment I must have been thinking about MASM that does remember sizes.
